# Android SmsReceiver crash my app if it's running in background when receive msn

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-dialog

If I am inside the app, I can check if i have received the SMS then Play Video. But If I press the home button and the app is running in the background, then if SMS is received the app will crash.

Thanks for your help guys.

**my code: inside the ** public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
...
         if (run this if corrected sms is received  ){

                    //Pause Video in PlayVideoActivity 
                    //PlayVideoActivity.mVideoView.pause();

                    /** Go to Dialog box 2 for Confirmation **/
                    PlayVideoActivity.DialogTextComfirmRun();

}
...
```

**the error SMS**

```
06-27 11:05:30.611: D/AndroidRuntime(707): Shutting down VM
06-27 11:05:30.631: W/dalvikvm(707): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.brazilapps.SmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.example.brazilapps.PlayVideoActivity.DialogTextComfirmRun(PlayVideoActivity.java:302)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.example.brazilapps.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:81)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
06-27 11:05:30.671: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  ... 10 more
```

**Someone advice me to** : tip: in ur receiver class file open an dialog activity - But I don't know how to open a dialog if the app is running in the background.

Any help is great. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can start an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver using this code:

```
puboic void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    ...
    if (run this if corrected sms is received ){
        // context can be the context object in the argument of onReceive method
        Intent i = new Intent(context, PlayVideoActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // use i.puExtra() to pass any data
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

After starting the Activity you can open dialog from the Activity or do anything that needs user interface.

And the logcat is showing a null pointer exception. So you should also add the code for PlayVideoActivity.DialogTextComfirmRun() method to find out what is wrong with the current approach.